# C pipes not communicating

Tags: c, process, ipc, fork, pipe

I have a coding assignment wherein I am to set up a ring of processes using fork(), and then pass a message through the ring.  now, the apparent issue at this point is that I cannot pass a message from the initial process to its directly connected child. (just doing 1 message pass as a test first)  However, I realize it could also be the case that the ring is not functioning correctly.  I would not be surprised if this was the case given that the message passing test i'm using is essentially example code verbatim, but then again, so is the code to form the ring...

so, my question is:  can anyone help me sort out what is going on wrong in my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int msg[2];
const int MAX = 100;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int master, i, child, num, pid, ppid, counter, loops;
    char buffer[MAX];
    num = atoi(argv[1]);
    loops = atoi(argv[2]);
    counter = 0;

    master = (int)getpid();

    //check num arguments
    if (argc != 4) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "incorrect # arguments");
    }
    pipe(msg);                      //create pipe
    dup2(msg[0], STDIN_FILENO);     //duplicate pipes
    dup2(msg[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(msg[0]);                  //close ends of pipe
    close(msg[1]);

    //create other processes
    for(i=1; i<num; i++) {
        pipe(msg);                  //create new pipe

        //create new process
        child = fork();             //parent has child id
        pid = (int)getpid();        //has own pid
        ppid = (int)getppid();      //has parent pid

        //if parent, fix output
        if(child > 0){
            dup2(msg[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        } else {
            dup2(msg[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        }
        close(msg[0]);
        close(msg[1]);
        if(child){
            break;
        }
    }

    //simple output
    fprintf(stderr, "process %d with id %d and parent id %d\n", i, pid, ppid);

    //message passing
    //if master, establish trasnfer
    if (pid == master) {
        //parent
        close(msg[0]);  //closes its read end
        char buffer[MAX];
        fprintf(stderr, "Parent: Waiting for input\n");
        while(1) {
            scanf("%s", buffer);
            if (strcmp(buffer, "exit")==0) {
               break;
            }
            write(msg[1], buffer, MAX);
        }
        close(msg[1]);  //closes it write end
    } else {
        //child
        close(msg[1]);  //closes its write end
        char buffer[MAX];
        fprintf(stderr, "Child: Waiting for pipe\n");
        while(read(msg[0], buffer, MAX) > 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Received: %s\n", buffer);
            buffer[0] = '\0';
        }
        close(msg[0]);  //closes its read end        
    }

    //special stuff for master node
    if(master == pid){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "i am the master");
        //special stuff
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "i am a child");
        //nothing really?
    }

    wait(2); //let all processes finish.
    exit(0);
}
```

i would be asking my instructor or TA, but they both decided to be out of town and away from email up to when the assignment is due.  if i cant get this working, its not the end of the world, but i'd like to avoid starting the course off with an incomplete coding assignment.

Comment: Is the parent process supposed to send a message to the first child, the first child send a message to the second child, etc, and finally the last child send a message back to the parent?

Comment: @Vaughn Please do not add the homework tag to questions. It has been deemed unnecessary and [officially deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147100).

Comment: @ughoavgfhw: wow, that's a big change -- thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @VaughnCato yes, that is most of the ultimate goal.  i was attempting to keep it as simple as i could for the moment

Comment: @ughoavgfhw: That is a big change, and a bad one IMO, totally disagree with the mods rationale on that one. Oh well.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, you'd better verify the command line arguments before you refer any of them (i.e. the code should be like

```
if (argc != 4) {
    ...
}

int num = atol(argv[1]);
```

)

I don't understand your code clearly and I'm sorry for my impatience.
Below is my solution with a code snippet to verify.
To establish the ring, first note processes are classified into two types: the master process, who initializes the IPC, and slaves.
Initially, we need two pipes, one for master to read from, the other for master to write to.
After initialization, two process is connected by pipes like this (P for parent, C for child).

```
C:+----------+-----------+
  |          |           |
  | Read End | Write End |
  |          |           |
  +----------+-----------+
         |\            \
           \            \
            \            \
             \            \
              \            \
P:+----------+-----------+  \
  |          |           |   \
  | Read End | Write End |    \
  |          |           |     \
  +----------+-----------+      |
       /|                       |
        |                       |
        +-----------------------+
```

Recursively, when new process forked, we want the connection evolve to:

```
   C2:+----------+-----------+
      |          |           |
      | Read End | Write End |
      |          |           |
      +----------+-----------+
             |\                \
               \                \
                \                \
                 \                \
                  \                \
   C1:+----------+-----------+      |
      |          |           |      |
      | Read End | Write End |      |
      |          |           |      |
      +----------+-----------+      |
             |\                     |
               \                    |
                \                   |
                 \                  |
                  \                 |
    P:+----------+-----------+      |
      |          |           |      |
      | Read End | Write End |      |
      |          |           |      |
      +----------+-----------+      |
           /|                       |
            |                       |
            +-----------------------+
```

So we need another pipe between C1 and C2，then redirect the I/O.
The following ASCII art illustrates this.

```
                                  C2:+----------+-----------+
                                     |          |           |
                                     | Read End | WriteEnd3 |
                                     |          |           |
                                     +----------+-----------+
                                             |\           \
                                               \           \
                                                \           \
                                                 \           \
   C1:+----------+-----------+       +----------+-----------+ |
      |          |           |       |          |           | |
      | Read End | WriteEnd1 |       | Read End | WriteEnd2 | |
      |          |           |       |          |           | |
      +----------+-----------+       +----------+-----------+ |
             |\            \              /|                  |
               \            \              |                  |
                \            \             +------------------+
                 \            \
                  \            \
    P:+----------+-----------+  \
      |          |           |   \
      | Read End | Write End |    \
      |          |           |     \
      +----------+-----------+      |
           /|                       |
            |                       |
            +-----------------------+
```

To form the ring, **WriteEnd2** should be dupped to **WriteEnd1**, thus child2 can read from child1. 
Also **WriteEnd1** should take place of **WriteEnd3** to write to master.

I include the sample code, however, you'd better understand what's going on to complete your homework not simply copy-and-paste:).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUF_LEN 32

int  input_pipe[2];
int output_pipe[2];

char buf[BUF_LEN];
const char msg[] = "hello world.\n";
int str_len = sizeof(msg);

int status;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    /* master input channel */
    int master_input;
    int ring_pid = 0;

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stdout, "Argument error!\n");
        fflush(stdout);

        exit(-1);
    }

    int total_processes = atoi(argv[1]);

    if (pipe(input_pipe) || pipe(output_pipe)) {
        fprintf(stdout, "Cannot create pipes at master. Program exits.\n");
        fflush(stdout);

        exit(-1);
    } else {
        /* fork child process */
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if (pid) {
            /* dup read end of input pipe and write end of output pipe. */
            int input_fd  = dup(input_pipe[0]);
            int output_fd = dup(output_pipe[1]);

            close(input_pipe[0]);
            close(input_pipe[1]);
            close(output_pipe[0]);
            close(output_pipe[1]);

            /* parent process */
            fprintf(stdout, "Send message to downstream: %s", msg);
            fflush(stdout);
            write(output_fd, msg, str_len + 1);

            read(input_fd, buf, BUF_LEN);
            fprintf(stdout, "Recieve message from upstream: %s", buf);
            fflush(stdout);

            waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
        } else {
            /* child process */
            /* write end of master's input pipe */
            master_input  = dup(input_pipe[1]);

            int input_fd  = dup(output_pipe[0]);
            int output_fd = -1;

            /* increase ring number */
            while (++ring_pid < total_processes) {
                int tmp_pipe[2];

                if (pipe(tmp_pipe)) {
                    fprintf(stdout, "Cannot create pipes at master. Program exits.\n");
                    fflush(stdout);

                    exit(-1);
                } else {
                    /* pid of sub-process's child */
                    pid_t spid = fork();
                    if (spid) {
                        /* drop read end of the pipe, we read from parent process */
                        close(tmp_pipe[0]);
                        /* output of last process directs to master's input */
                        if (ring_pid == total_processes - 1) {
                            output_fd = dup(master_input);
                        } else {
                            output_fd = dup(tmp_pipe[1]);
                        }
                        close(tmp_pipe[1]);
                        /* receive and send message */
                        read(input_fd, buf, BUF_LEN);
                        fprintf(stdout, "Read from upstream: %s", buf);

                        fprintf(stdout, "Write to downstream: %s", buf);
                        write(output_fd, buf, BUF_LEN);

                        waitpid(spid, &status, 0);
                        break;
                    } else {
                        /* for child process, the input is read end of the new pipe. */
                        input_fd = dup(tmp_pipe[0]);
                        close(tmp_pipe[0]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing I can suggest is to use this style when forking processes:

```
child_pid = fork();
if (child_pid==0) {
  childProcess(); // isolate the child process logic
  _exit(0); // make sure the execution doesn't escape the if statement
}
```

I think that will help you see some of the logic problems in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to read your input using `scanf`, which reads from standard input. However, one of the first things you did was close the original standard input by duplicating the read end of your first pipe over it. Therefore, you are attempting to read the input from the pipe. To fix this, you should save the read end of the first pipe in a variable for the master to read from later, but not duplicate it over standard input.

Also, when you attempt to read or write to the pipe, you are using the descriptors stored in `msg`, but you closed those descriptors while creating your chain. You need to read/write to the standard input/output descriptors, where you duplicated the pipes. You also (attempt to) close the unused end of the pipe chain before reading/writing, but when you start using the whole chain that will no longer be unused.

For example, a loop of 4 processes could look like this:

```
 input(stdin)
   v
+> A -+
|     v
D     B
^     |
+- C <+
```

After creating all of the processes, each connection is either standard input or output, except for the chain returning to process A (the master). Process A reads from standard input and writes to standard output, which is connected to process B's standard input. Process B then reads its standard input and writes to its standard output, passing the message on to process C. Processes C and D do the same thing, passing the message all of the way around the loop and back to process A on the read port of the original pipe. Since each process is responsible for both reading and writing, neither of its pipes should be closed until after it is completely finished.

Comment: i'm not sure i understand.  are you saying i should not close any of the ends of my pipe's and that i should not use stdin/stdout for message passing?  this is all terribly confusing to me...

Comment: I added an example. You can use stdin/out for message passing if you want, but the master's standard input must be saved to read the message from the terminal. Your loop creating the process is closing unused pipes fine, but the ones that are left need to stay open until after the message has gone through, and then you are actually using stdin/out, so those are the ones you would close.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm needs to be changed. The logic, here is that if you have n children, then you need to have n + 1 pipes.

Now you need to store the ends of the pipes in a suitable data structure. I have used a two dimensional array, where each row means one pipe and say column 0 is the read end and column 1 is the write end of a particular pipe.(pl consider making this array dynamic)

Now for every child, we need two ends one read end,  and the other write end. Now here these ends will be coming from two different pipes.This is the logic.

***That means say we consider child1, who gets read end from pipe1 and write end from pipe2. Now child0 should be  having write end from pipe1 and child2 should be  having read end from pipe2.Hope the idea is clear.***

(Now another criteria is that the processes,  need to behave as a **filter** that is they read from standard input and write into standard output. This is done using the dup2 function which will duplicate the respective pipe descriptors for reading and writing,  to standard input and output)

I am providing a sample code below with some comments, which will help you understand the concept.

(There are hardcoded values and very less error handling. This you should add.)

```
#define MAXCHILD 50
#define NO_OF_CHILDREN 20
#define MAXBUF 100

void child(int readend, int writeend);
int main()
{
int pipefd[MAXCHILD + 1][2];
int noofchildren = 0;
int nchild = NO_OF_CHILDREN;
int ret;
int i ;
char buf[MAXBUF];
for(i = 0; i <= nchild; i++)
{
    ret = pipe(pipefd[i]);
    if (0 > ret)
    {
        printf("Pipe Creation failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}
printf("Pipes created\n");

for(i = 0; i < nchild; i++)
{

    ret = fork();
    if (0 == ret)
    {
        child(pipefd[i][0], pipefd[i + 1][1]);
    }
    //These ends are no longer needed in parent.
    close (pipefd[i][0]);
    close(pipefd[i + 1][1]);
}

printf("%d Children  Created\n", nchild);

while(1) 
{
    printf("Enter Some data\n");
    //Now the parent/master reads from the standard input
    fgets(buf, MAXBUF, stdin);
    //Write to the pipe which is connected to the first child.
    write(pipefd[0][1],buf, strlen(buf) + 1);
    //Read from the pipe, which is attached to the last child created
    read(pipefd[nchild][0], buf, MAXBUF);
    printf("Master Read from the pipe - %s\n", buf);
    if (strcmp(buf, "exit\n") == 0)
    {
        break;
    }
} 
//By this time all other children, would have exited
//Let's wait to see this 
while(1)
{
    ret = wait(NULL);
    if (0 > ret) //Returns -ve when no more child is left.
    {
        break;
    }
    noofchildren++;
}
printf("My %d children terminated! Now I am exiting", noofchildren);
exit(0);
}

void child(int readend, int writeend)
{
char buf[MAXBUF];
int ret;
//set up environment
dup2(readend, 0);
dup2(writeend,1);   
while(1)
{
    ret = read(0, buf, MAXBUF );
    if (strcmp(buf, "exit\n") == 0)
    {
        write(1, buf, ret);
        exit(0);
    }
    write(1, buf, ret);
}
}
```